# ¿Como puedo modificar el valor total al momento de modificar un dato de cantidad o precio unitario?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="caja6">
```

## DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS

```
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
   <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">Nueva</div>
 </label>
 <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
  <tr>
    <th>Detalles De Insumos</th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Valor Total ($)</th>
    <th>OPCION</th>
  </tr>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($detalle_insumo); ++$i) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" id="detalle_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_insumo[$i][0] ?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" id="unidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_unidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_insumo[]" id="cantidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_cantidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" id="precio_unitario_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_precio_unitario_dia[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" id="valor_total_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_valor_total[$i][0] ?>" readonly ></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class='btn btn-info'>Eliminar</div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

```
  function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo(){ $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
.append
(
  $('<tr>')
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]')
    )
   )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').prop('readonly', true)
    )
   )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

    .append
    (
      $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-info').text('Eliminar')
      )        

    )        
  );

sumaValores();}


introducir el código aquí//Creo una función donde voy a sumar todos los valores totales de la última columna var sumaTotales = function(){//Inicializo en 0 el valor a establecer indicando el resultado de la sumatoria var totales = 0;//Recorro todas las filas de la tabla $('tr','#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){
 //Obtengo el campo del cual quiero tomar el valor para sumarlo
 var campo_total = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');
 //Agrego a totales el nuevo valor
 var numero = parseInt(campo_total.val()); totales += isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;});//Establezco el resultado de la suma $('#valor_unitario').val(totales); $('#suma_1').val(totales);};//Esta tabla es para agregar Detalle materiales, repuestos e insumos var sumaValores = function(){
//Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
var fila = $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr:last');
//Obtengo el campo referente a la cantidad de insumo ':eq(2)'
var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)'); 

//Obtengo el campo referente al precio_unitario_insumo ':eq(3)'
var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');
//Obtengo el campo donde se escribirá el resultado
var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');


campo1.on('change', function(){
  destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
    //Llamo a la función para que se actualice cada vez que se cambie algo en este campo
    sumaTotales();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  });

campo2.on('change', function(){
  destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
    //Llamo a la función para que se actualice cada vez que se cambie algo en este campo
    sumaTotales();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  }); };
```

Comment: @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas, disculpa que te vuelva a molestar, pero necesito de tu ayuda. saludos

Comment: O alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no miro algún botón para calcular, me imagino que quieres hacer el calculo cada vez que cambie el input. Habrá que ejecutar un evento de cambio para realizarlo.
*No olvides agregarlo también en donde generas el nuevo renglón

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" id="detalle_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_insumo[$i][0] ?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" id="unidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_unidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control setTotal" name="cantidad_insumo[]" id="cantidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_cantidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control setTotal" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" id="precio_unitario_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_precio_unitario_dia[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" id="valor_total_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_valor_total[$i][0] ?>" readonly ></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class='btn btn-info'>Eliminar</div>

    </td>

$(".setTotal").change(function {
    setTotal();
});
```

Después para ejecutar el calculo, la opción que te presento, recorriendo los tr de la tabla (forech) y resolviendo en base a la posición de los td (td:eq(posicion)).

```
   function setTotal(){
       $("tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr').each(function (idx, row) {
                if (idx > 0) {
                        var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(2) input').val();
                        var precio = $(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val();
                        var importe = cantidad * precio;
                        $(this).find('td:eq(4) input').val(importe );
            });
    }
```

Comment: Es todo automatico @Aaron por eso no existe boton

Comment: eso lo coloco en la funcion o en el html?

Comment: Es la función de setTotal

Comment: $(".setTotal").change(function {
    setTotal();
});  Donde va eso???

Comment: En cualquier parte de tu script, es el evento que lanza al función

Comment: no hace nada :(

Comment: es que lo puse todo en un archivo que se llama edicion.js , pero no hace nada

Comment: O quizas esta mal puesto, si lo pudieras subir bien te lo agradeceria

Comment: ayuda plisssssss

Comment: me puedes confirmar si te llego la etiqueta

Comment: La cabo de mirar, haz el recorrido y generes tus 20 de reputación, en el chat te podré guiar correctamente

Comment: tblUnidades de donde sale esta?